# In what situations is a one sample T-Test superior to a two sample T-Test?

Tags: statistical-significance, confidence-interval, t-test, control-group

I'm trying to make a case for more use and respect of one-sample t-test in medical studies (which are generally looked down upon, wrongfully so imo).  I see that in general medical studies prefer at least two samples, an intervention and a control.  I personally see that this can in some cases be inferior to a one sample T-Test, but I want to know if I am right by asking the experts here, and to see if there are other cases than the following where one-sample tests can be superior.

In one case that I can think of where a one-sample t-test analysis is superior (and again, I'm seeking for validation, as well as other ideas), it is when the control of a two-sample test is a small enough population (compared to the intervention group) that it can adversely affect the confidence of the result.

Also, and this is a function of experimental design so it should be avoided, if the conditions for the control vs intervention are too different (time, location, operator, etc) it can introduce more and more disparate unanticipated variables than simply comparing a one-sample with a standard condition.  Again, this should be avoidable by proper DOE but it does suggest that two-sample can become more troublesome if not done right.  By the same token such a research may invest more confidence in the bogus result than they would if it were just a one-sample test.

It also seems like the advantages of a two-sample T-test tend to go away as the population for a one-sample T-test goes up (especially as it gets very large), and as the averages for all other variables for that population (eg. weather, opinions, dispositions, diets, age distribution, etc) approach that of the average or standard values.  Am I making sense here, or just in my head ... I'm sorry I'm not doing a very good job of explaining my thoughts.  This can be done by simply increasing the population, or through validation studies elsewhere by other parties where problematic variables (times, place, operator, equipment, coincidental conditions, etc) have enough natural variation to cover most situations.

Comment: To what would you compare your treatment outcomes?

Comment: Dave - That's a good point ... the answer to this question depends on the situation.  One situation I am thinking of is standard care for sepsis patients vs a new drug.  Interested primarily in survival.  A dozen hospitals are using the new drug and the results have consistently increased survival from 50% to 90%, but most hospitals (like 98% of them) refuse to do it until a number of RCTs are done.  Sepsis is the #1 killer in hospitals.

Comment: I guess 2 more ways in which they are superior I'm not really sure I would use as arguments: time and money.  One-sample tests are cheaper and faster than two-sample tests ... but this is actually looked down upon in medical circles where it is presumed it comes at the expense of data-integrity and study quality.

Comment: Expertise is another one where it seems RCTs often fail more often. RCT's are often packaged together by a investigational team who tries to make a cookie cutter recipe for any hospital willing to try it. These are often poorly designed / implemented. Investigational team members are often critics of the intervention, they're sloppy, key things are missed (like timing, dose, compliance, contraindications, methodology, etc), and the test becomes designed to fail. One-sample test are normally implemented by doctors hoping for improvement so they follow the best protocol the best that they can.

Comment: Though it has little to do with the tests your are asking about, single-arm studies are very common in early trials of new interventions. These are, however, not typically powered for efficacy.

Comment: Bryan, good point ... in fact I think often this isn't done enough and too often I see a new intervention rushed into an RCT before they've even determined where the optimal efficacy is nor have they explored or verified safety limits.